# Grep grammatical clauses

Tags: regex, awk, grep, clause

I'm trying to find a way to grep grammatical clauses from an ebook sample.
Here's what the input looks like:

```
This is a test my friend, this is just a test; I'm going to do some shopping:`what do you need?`
Nothing, he said.
```

Desired output:

```
This is a test my friend
this is just a test
I'm going to do shopping
what do you need
Nothing
he said
```

Any ideas on how one could achieve this?

Thank you very much !

Comment: What do you want to do about clauses that are spread over a couple of lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use gnu-awk like this:

```
awk -v RS='[\n.,;:`?]+' -v ORS='\n' '{$1=$1} 1' file
This is a test my friend
this is just a test
I'm going to do some shopping
what do you need
Nothing
he said
```

Answer (score 1):

This comes close:

```
grep -o '[[:alpha:][:space:]]\+' file
```

but it translates the single quote in "I'm" to a newline. Given your example punctuation, this works:

```
grep -o '[^,;:`?.]\+' file
```

This will keep the space after a punctuation character. To remove it, pipe the output to

```
| sed 's/^ //'
```

Answer (score 0):

Pipe it to tr.

```
cat input | tr ',' '\n'
```

Comment: I think you need to worry about colons, backquotes, semicolons, full stops (periods), question marks, etc, but the basic idea looks right.  Does `-s` help?  Also, if there's a single input file, then I/O redirection is sufficient.  In general, piping is necessary.